# Finding an element of the desired type in the GameObject[] array using LINQ

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I did a search for an element of the required data type in the GameObject[] array, but I would like to do it via LINQ, how do I do it?

I did it through the foreach loop, but I need to through LINQ

```
private void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode loadSceneMode)
{
    if (scene.buildIndex == 2)
    {
        var sceneObjects = scene.GetRootGameObjects();
        foreach (var obj in sceneObjects)
        {
            if(obj.GetComponent<SumoUIManager>())
                sumoUIManager = obj.GetComponent<SumoUIManager>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"but I need to through LINQ"_ - any particular reason why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the LINQ `First` or `FirstOrDefault` method, you should be able to filter the `sumoUIManager` from the array:

```
var sumoUIManager = sceneObjects.FirstOrDefault(x => x is SumoUIManager);
```

Note: `First` will throw an exception if there is no object of the `SumoUIManager` type in the array whereas `FirstOrDefault` will return null.

Answer (score 1):

In LINQ, the above code would be as follows:

```
var sceneObjects = scene.GetRootGameObjects();
var sumoUIManager = sceneObjects
    .Where(obj => obj.GetComponent<SumoUIManager>() != null)
    .Select(obj => obj.GetComponent<SumoUIManager>())
    .FirstOrDefault();
```